# What metadata does a LibreOffice file contain and how to remove it?

Tags: privacy, libreoffice, metadata

I am using LibreOffice on Linux. One way I know of viewing and removing metadata from a LibreOffice file is going to `File -> Properties -> General`, unchecking  “apply user data” and click reset. Then go to “Description” and “Custom” Properties and remove information from there, if exists.

Does it truly remove all the metadata or something is left and what is it and what other methods can I use to remove it?

Also, if I unzip a LibreOffice file, is `contents.xml` the only place where metadata may be found?

If I forgot to remove any metadata, is it possible that the username is transmitted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. The method in my question is not enough, because it doesn't remove all metadata! It doesn't delete metadata such as *editing-duration*, *editing-cycles* and *generator*. *generator* contains your LibreOffice version and operating system, I don't know why the developers didn't mention that anywhere.

To remove metadata from a LibreOffice file:

1. If your file is document.odt, rename it to document.zip
2. Open the zip and remove the meta.xml file
3. Rename from document.zip back to document.odt. **If you open the file after that, edit it and save it, metadata will get written into it again so don't edit the file after removing the metadata.**

Tip: use *exiftool* to check the metadata before and after.

If there is any other identifying information or information that make fingerprinting possible inside the document please comment or edit the question or add your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to remove the `PrinterName` and `PrinterSetup` config items in `settings.xml` since they also contain potentially identifying information.

Steps:

1. If your file is document.odt, rename it to document.zip
2. Open the zip and edit the settings.xml file
3. Remove the `<config:config-item config:name="PrinterSetup" [...] </config:config-item>` and `<config:config-item config:name="PrinterName" [...] </config:config-item>` XML elements.

Apart from that I found no other problematic content.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).